# Replacing first column csv with variable

Tags: bash, csv, sed, awk

I can't believe I couldn't find my question anywhere else in the bash/linux community. I simply want to replace the first column of my csv file with a variable...

```
0,8,9,10
0,8,9,10
0,8,9,10
0,8,9,10
0,8,9,10
0,8,9,10


2/24/14,8,9,10
2/24/14,8,9,10
2/24/14,8,9,10
2/24/14,8,9,10
2/24/14,8,9,10
2/24/14,8,9,10
```

I simply just want to replace the first column with `$date`, but all the awk commands don't allow a variable as a the replacement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
awk -v dt="$date" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$1=dt}1' inputFile
```

**Explaination:**

- Use `-v` option to set an `awk` variable and assign it your `shell` variable.
- Set the Input Field Separator and Output Field Separator to `,` (since it is a csv)
- Set the value of `$1` to your `awk` variable.
- `1` is to print the line with modified `$1`.

Comment: Very well explained @Jaypal +1

Comment: That's the first time I've received an explanation of the `1` after the curly brackets or parentheses (round brackets.) That helps me understand some other commands.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's#^[^,]*#2/24/14#' filename
```

should do it.  If you want to work with the current date, you should do:

```
DATE=$(date +'%d/%m/%y')
sed "s#^[^,]*#$DATE#" filename
```

This is looking for the first item before the comma and replace it with the date.  The use of `#` as delimiter allows you to type in the date without having to escape the `/` character.

Comment: `sed "s|[^,]*|$( date +'%d/%m/%y' )|" YourFile` do all at once

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 's/.*?,/2\/24\/14/' your_file
```

tested [here](http://ideone.com/qlNn0h)

Answer (score 1):

Every time you deal with complex data format you should use proper parser and CSV is complex data format (and without any proper definition and full of quirks. No RFC 4180 is not the definition. It is rather joke. There is a lot of data violating RFC 4180 and almost every decent CSV parser out there is ignoring this RFC because it would not work.)

```
perl -mText::CSV_XS -e'$d=shift@ARGV;$csv=Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1, eol => $/ });while(my$row=$csv->getline(*ARGV)){$$row[0]=$d;$csv->print(*STDOUT,$row)}' "$date"
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing to current date using `awk`

```
echo "0,8,9,10" | awk '{sub(/[^,]+/,d)}8' d="$(date +'%d/%m/%y')"
25/02/14,8,9,10
```

`[^,]+` everything that is not a `,` will be replaced with `d` date